# In python, is there an efficient way of seperating an array with elements mapped to another array?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, sorting

Let's say i have an arbitrary array `np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])` with another array that maps specific elements in the array to a group, `np.array(['a','b', 'a','c','c', 'b'])` and now I want to seperate them into three different array depending on the label/group given in the second array, so that they are `a,b,c = narray([1,3]), narray([2,6]), narray([4,5])`. Is a simple forloop the way to go or is there some efficient method I'm missing here?

Comment: You can simply use predefined numpy splitting function:
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])

newarr = np.array_split(arr, 3)

print(newarr[0])
print(newarr[1])
print(newarr[2])

Output :
[1 2]
[3 4]
[5 6]

Comment: @AliHassan That's not the output OP wants though.

Comment: it helps to have a script that at least initializes arrays - and perhaps includes your best guess of a solution - so that answers can start from the same chunk of code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you write efficient, I assume that what you want here is actually *fast*.

I will try to discuss briefly asymptotic efficiency.
In this context, we refer to `N` as the input size and `K` as the number of unique values.

My approach solution would be to use a combination of [`np.argsort()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) and a custom-built `groupby_np()` specifically optimized for NumPy inputs:

```
import numpy as np


def groupby_np(arr, both=True):
    n = len(arr)
    extrema = np.nonzero(arr[:-1] != arr[1:])[0] + 1
    if both:
        last_i = 0
        for i in extrema:
            yield last_i, i
            last_i = i
        yield last_i, n
    else:
        yield 0
        yield from extrema
        yield n


def labeling_groupby_np(values, labels):
    slicing = labels.argsort()
    sorted_labels = labels[slicing]
    sorted_values = values[slicing]
    del slicing
    result = {}
    for i, j in groupby_np(sorted_labels, True):
        result[sorted_labels[i]] = sorted_values[i:j]
    return result
```

This has complexity `O(N log N + K)`.
The `N log N` comes from the sorting step and the `K` comes from the last loop.
The interesting part is that the both the `N`-dependent and the `K`-dependent steps are fast because the `N`-dependent part is executed at low level, and the `K`-dependent part is `O(1)` and also fast.

---

A solution like the following (very similar to [@theEpsilon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64125921/5218354) answer):

```
import numpy as np


def labeling_loop(values, labels):
    labeled = {}
    for x, l in zip(values, labels):
        if l not in labeled:
            labeled[l] = [x]
        else:
            labeled[l].append(x)
    return {k: np.array(v) for k, v in labeled.items()}
```

uses two loops and has `O(N + K)`. I do not think you can easily avoid the second loop (without a significant speed penalty). As for the first loop, this is executed in Python, which carries a significant speed penalty on its own.

---

Another possibility is to use [`np.unique()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) which brings the *main loop* to a lower level. However, this brings other challenges, because once the unique values  are extracted, there is no efficient way of extracting the information to construct the arrays you want without some [NumPy advanced indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing), which is `O(N)`. The overall complexity of these solutions is then `O(K * N)`, but because the NumPy advanced indexing is done at lower level, this can land to relatively fast solution, although with a worse asymptotic complexity than alternatives.

Possible implementations include (similar to [@AjayVerma's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14239429/ajay-verma) and [@AKX's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64125903/5218354) answers):

```
import numpy as np


def labeling_unique_bool(values, labels):
    return {l: values[l == labels] for l in np.unique(labels)}
```

```
import numpy as np


def labeling_unique_nonzero(values, labels):
    return {l: values[np.nonzero(l == labels)] for l in np.unique(labels)}
```

Additionally, one could consider a pre-sorting step to then speed up the slicing part by avoiding NumPy advanced indexing.
However, the sorting step can be more costly than the advanced indexing, and in general the proposed approach tends to be faster for the input I tested.

```
import numpy as np


def labeling_unique_argsort(values, labels):
    uniques, counts = np.unique(labels, return_counts=True)
    sorted_values = values[labels.argsort()]
    bound = 0
    result = {}
    for x, c in zip(uniques, counts):
        result[x] = sorted_values[bound:bound + c]
        bound += c
    return result
```

---

Another approach, which is neat in principle (same as my proposed approach), but slow in practice would be to use sorting and [`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
import itertools
from operator import itemgetter


def labeling_groupby(values, labels):
    slicing = labels.argsort()
    sorted_labels = labels[slicing]
    sorted_values = values[slicing]
    del slicing
    result = {}
    for x, g in itertools.groupby(zip(sorted_labels, sorted_values), itemgetter(0)):
        result[x] = np.fromiter(map(itemgetter(1), g), dtype=sorted_values.dtype)
    return result
```

---

Finally, a Pandas based approach, which is quite concise and reasonably fast for larger inputs, but under-performing for smaller ones (similar to [@Ehsan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64129835/5218354)):

```
def labeling_groupby_pd(values, labels):
    df = pd.DataFrame({'values': values, 'labels': labels})
    return df.groupby('labels').values.apply(lambda x: x.values).to_dict()
```

---

Now, talking is cheap, so let us attach some numbers to *fast* and *slow* and produce some plots for varying input sizes. The value of `K` is capped to 52 (lower and upper case letters of the English alphabet). When `N` is much larger than `K`, the probability of reaching capping value is very high.

Input is generated programmatically with the following:

```
def gen_input(n, p, labels=string.ascii_letters):
    k = len(labels)
    values = np.arange(n)
    labels = np.array([string.ascii_letters[i] for i in np.random.randint(0, int(k * p), n)])
    return values, labels
```

and the benchmarks are produced for values of `p` from `(1.0, 0.5, 0.1, 0.05)`, which change the maximum value of `K`. The plots below refer to the `p` values in that order.

---

**p=1.0** (at most `K = 52`)

[image: bm_p100]

...and zoomed on the fastest

[image: bm_p100_zoom]

---

**p=0.5** (at most `K = 26`)

[image: bm_p50]

---

**p=0.1** (at most `K = 5`)

[image: bm_p10]

---

**p=0.05** (at most `K = 2`)

[image: bm_p5]

...and zoomed on the fastest

[image: bm_p5_zoom]

---

One can see how the proposed method, except for very small inputs, outperforms the other methods proposed so far for the tested inputs.

(Full benchmarks available [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1p3QCjZoRvmuALjc74X8FnUXMOBqtoTg9?usp=sharing)).

---

One may also consider moving some parts of the looping to Numba / Cython, but I'd leave this to the interested reader.

Comment: Why is the Pandas solution so comparatively slow for small inputs?

Comment: Big O isn't everything, but it's nice to see I won with that 

Comment: While I like all the detailed analysis, I think it is not necessarily the best comparison. I think a lot of these differences in time comes from the overhead of creating the correct data structure. I would recommend OP to run the same analysis as yours with removing possible overheads of data creation from the get-go and having in mind what structure is required for the output. Having that said, great analysis.

Comment: @IdeaO. I think most of constant overhead goes into creating the DataFrame but I am not 100% sure

Comment: @Ehsan There is some overhead for creating a uniform result across solutions, but that is relevant only for very small inputs. See the [benchmarks with "native" containers](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1j6Cleu4tiJvM6T8cLCZ7KA-Ee6jP0Ojr?usp=sharing).

Comment: God damn, didn't expect this amount of help even from stackoverflow. Very helpful thank you all!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `numpy.unique`

```py
x = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])
y = np.array(['a','b', 'a','c','c', 'b'])
print({value:x[y==value] for value in np.unique(y)})
```

**Output**

```py
{'a': array([1, 3]), 'b': array([2, 6]), 'c': array([4, 5])}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a textbook use of pandas groupby:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3,4,5,6],'B':['a','b','a','c','c','b']})
a,b,c = df.groupby('B').A.apply(lambda x:x.values)
#[1 3], [2 6], [4 5]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm *sure* there's some simple invocation to do all in one fell swoop and a Numpy guru will soon enlighten us, but

```
indices = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])
values = np.array(['a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'c', 'b'])
indices_by_value = {}
for value in np.unique(values):
  indices_by_value[value] = indices[values == value]
```

will leave you with

```
{'a': array([1, 3]), 'b': array([2, 6]), 'c': array([4, 5])}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```py
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
letters = ['a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'c', 'b']
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
for l, n in zip(letters, numbers):
    d[l].append(n)
```

And d will have your answer.

Comment: OP has Numpy arrays, not bare Python lists. This might work, but it won't be as efficient as it can be using Numpy indexing. (That said, for non-Numpy iterables this is a good approach.)

Comment: @AKX Someone in an O(n^2) glass house should maybe not try to throw stones at someone else's O(n) house :-P

Comment: Not a competition. I think any well explained answer is educational and can be helpful to future readers for various purposes. I like all the different ways coders think to resolve a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Using the mask selection feature of numpy should do the work.
Something like this :

```py
> import numpy as np
> xx = np.array(range(5))
> yy = np.array(['a','b','a','d','e'])
> yy=='a'
 array([ True, False,  True, False, False])
> xx[(yy=='a')]
array([0, 2])
```

Consider browsing the unique values of your array of label and build a dictionnary of matches incrementally.